# How should I interpret this circuit?

Tags: relay, coupling

[image]

This circuit is a coupling relay circuit distributed.

[image]

Looking at this circuit makes sense.
Thank you for answer.

Comment: Welcome to the forum. This is not a good question for a variety of reasons and will be down voted or closed unless you revise and improve it. Please see the [FAQ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on how to ask a good question on this site.

Comment: It is an optocoupler with extra protection. It can be simply viewed as an optocoupler the has a phototransistor. The transistor is npn as the emitter arrow is pointing outwards.  Why do you doubt this circuit? There’s probably a million of them in the field all happily working.

Answer (score 2):

As drawn, it is an NPN transistor.  The part name says so and the schematic symbol says so.  It is not a PNP transistor unless you've drawn it wrong and written the name wrong.

This circuit isolates the input (pins A1 and A2) from the output (pins 13 and 14.)

It causes pin 13 and 14 to connect when current flows through A1 and A2.

You would connect pin 14 to ground on whatever circuit you are driving (a PLC or microcontroller) and connect pin 13 to the digital input on the controller.  Current through A1 and A2 will then cause the phototransistor to pull the digital input low.